# Problem adding the new users to CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Recently, I have installed CRM dynamics 4.0.

It is working fine.

Already, five users are there, but I have to add another user.

However, I did not find the add new user button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct permissions to add a new user?